# How to find if there's cyclic dependency in JSON Schema

Tags: java, json, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a function that generates JSON schema in the draft 7 specification(passed as JSONObject), based on given params. I have to add a check function after the JSON Schema is created, to check if the JSON Schema is cyclic or not.

I am currently thinking of using a tree. I am using simple pseudocode like this to validate the tree. But I am not able to figure out how we can convert that specification into a tree and add a dependency between two nodes. Currently just planning to add child node in the array of childNodes of parent node.

```
public Boolean checkCycling(JSONSchemaObject jsonSchema) {
    if (jsonSchema.isVisited()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        jsonSchema.setVisited(true);
        for (JSONSchemaObject node : jsonSchema.childNodes()) {
            checkCycling(node);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there an existing library in java that does this? I just want to check if the given JSOn schema is cyclic or not. Any other solution will help as well.

Comment: One of the laziest method would be to roam recursively the three and if you `catch` any `StackOverflowError`, you have a cyclic dependency

Comment: I am doing something similar. The issue with the tree approach is, that I am finding it difficult to create a tree from JSON schema. Like I can create nodes, but connecting with $ref is a little bit confusing, as it can have so many cases to refer to another object